# Docker-Compose file has yaml.scanner.ScannerError but i don´t see anything

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

when i try to compose i get shown this:

```
    yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 15
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
    fhem:
        restart:always
        expose:
            - "8083"
            - "7072"
        ports:
            - "8083:8083"
            - "7072:7072"
        build: fhem
        privileged: true
        devices:
          - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0"
       ....
```

can´t see any wrong syntax at all

Comment: `restart:always` -> `restart: always`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space after the colon following `restart` (per @bartimar), and your device line isn't indented correctly, since you're using 4 space indent.

```
version: '2'

services:
    fhem:
        restart: always
        expose:
            - "8083"
            - "7072"
        ports:
            - "8083:8083"
            - "7072:7072"
        build: fhem
        privileged: true
        devices:
            - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

Comment: If a 4 space indent is wrong, what exactly it the correct number of spaces for indentation in this file?

Comment: @zipzit The original post mixed in a 2 space indent underneath the `devices` column which can yield a yaml linting error. I can't remember if docker-compose breaks because of it, but I suspect it might have; which is why I posted a separate answer rather than only upvoting the comment from @bartimar. You can do 2, or 4, or whatever number of spaces you choose but yaml expects you to be consistent with your indentation levels.